# Can the word "managed" be used for sarcasm?

Tags: meaning, sarcasm

Pere Tanguy says to Armand about Vincent:

> Pere Tanguy: He joined his uncle's art dealership and was thrown out
> in disgrace. He tried for his father's profession, the church, but the
> pastor exams were too hard for him, so he took a job as a lowly
> missionary. He **managed** to get sacked even from that.

Can the word "managed" be used for sarcasm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly, almost *any* word can be used in sarcasm. Some examples of sarcastic language:

- That was really *smart*, skating on thin ice.
- You *managed* to soak yourself from head to foot.
- You've *achieved* a new level of carelessness.

The italicized words normally have a *positive* [connotation](https://literarydevices.net/connotation/), but in sarcasm, are used with these negative events.